# Telling the difference between two large pieces of text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, algorithm

What would be the best way to compare big paragraphs of text in order to tell the differences apart.  For example string A and string B are the same except for a few missing words, how would I highlight these?

Originally I thought of breaking it down into word arrays, and comparing the elements.  However this breaks down when a word is deleted or inserted.

Comment: runing a standard diff/delta algorithm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [diff algorithm](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm).

Answer (score 1):

I saw this a few months back when I was working on a small project, but it might set you on the right track.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into *Longest Common Subsequence* algorithms. Most languages have a library which will do the dirty work for you, and [here](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/default.aspx) is one for C#. Searching for "C# diff" or "VB.Net diff" will help you find additional libraries that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually text difference is measured in terms of [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), which is essentially **the number of character additions, deletions or changes necessary to transform one text into the other**.

A common implementation of this algorithm uses [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementaion of a Merge Engine that compares 2 html files and shows the highlighted differences: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/htmltextcompare.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-shot deal, save them both in MS Word and use the document compare function.

Comment: Nah this'll be a recurring thing thats needs to happen in code behind on an ASP.net webapp